# How to format embedded if statements in javascript

Tags: javascript

What would be the best way to format this code?

It looks a bit messy to me, in regard to indentation, etc.

```
    if (typeof _srwc != 'undefined') {
        for (var i=0; i < _srwc.length; i++){
             var currentArg = _srwc[i];;        
              if (typeof window[currentArg[0]] == 'function') {
                 window[currentArg[0]](currentArg[1], currentArg[2], currentArg[3]);
                 } else {
                 console.log('The Setter method: "' + currentArg[0] + '" is undefined');
                 }
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try indenting the code inside the if, like this:

```
    if (typeof _srwc != 'undefined') {
        for (var i = 0; i < _srwc.length; i++) {
            var currentArg = _srwc[i];;
            if (typeof window[currentArg[0]] == 'function') {
                window[currentArg[0]](currentArg[1], currentArg[2], currentArg[3]);
            } else {
                console.log('The Setter method: "' + currentArg[0] + '" is undefined');
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org) is very useful for indenting JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
if (typeof _srwc != 'undefined')
{
    for (var i = 0; i < _srwc.length; i++)
    {
        var currentArg = _srwc[i];
        if (typeof window[currentArg[0]] == 'function')
        {
            window[currentArg[0]](currentArg[1], currentArg[2], currentArg[3]);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('The Setter method: "' + currentArg[0] + '" is undefined');
        }
    }
}
```

That way all opening brackets are on the same vertical line as the closing ones and you can easily track which closing bracket is the one for a selected opening one (the first one below it on the same spacing distance). It's easier to trask the code that way if you're not using an IDE that is coloring the coresponding brackets.

Answer (score 1):

When coding any language, normally entering a new block would cause indentation and exiting the same block does the opposite.  (JS indentation should be 4 spaces)

ie

```
function xyz(){
    alert("xyz");
}
```

and

```
function abc(){
    if(true){
        alert("true");
    }else{
        alert("false");    
    }
    alert("abc");
}
```

..but like me if you get lazy and stop indenting using a tool like [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) whcih are available in most languages online just give it a search.

Comment: Note: Code blocks are {}